# Is there a way to recreate specific versions based of other versions?

Tags: carrierwave

I crop the big version based on the original version that is left uncropped, I then wan't to recreate the same crop on the small version. Is there a way to recreate it based on the version big instead of calculating the crop based on the difference in the dimensions?

```
version :big do
 process :crop
 process :resize_to_fill => [600, 400]
 process :convert => 'jpg'
end`


version :thumb do
 process :resize_to_fill => [100, 80]
 process :convert => 'jpg'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you can nest version within version by doing

```
version :big do
  #process...

  version :thumb do
    #process...
  end
end
```

But I haven't use that feature, so I don't know is the subversion will have the parent processes applied.

Comment: Seems like it supposed to but not sure if it does, will try it. https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/53 https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/pull/168 https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/pull/207

Comment: Well that worked but I no longer get the thumb in the JSON representation. Any idea how I would add it ?